# How to get the first element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you get the first element from an array like this:

```
var ary = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
```

I tried this:

```
alert($(ary).first());
```

But it would return `[object Object]`. So I need to get the first element from the array which should be the element `'first'`.

Comment: I strongly recommend sorting the answers by **active**

Answer (score 521, accepted):

like this

```
alert(ary[0])
```

Comment: This assumes that the first element in the array is always has an index of 0. You know what they say about assumption...

Comment: `ary[-1] = 'alert';`

Answer (score 246):

Why are you jQuery-ifying a vanilla JavaScript array? Use standard JavaScript!

```
var ary = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
alert(ary[0]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Also,
[image: needs more jQuery]

[Source](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery), courtesy of [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506725/1128918) on why this solution does not always work.

Answer (score 209):

Some of ways below for different circumstances.

In most normal cases, the simplest way to access the first element is by

```
yourArray[0]
```

but this requires you to check if `[0]` actually exists.

Another commonly used method is [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) but you should avoid using this for the purpose of accessing the first element.

Well, this method modifies the original array (removes the first item and returns it) but re-indexes what is left in the array to make it start from 0 (shifts everything down). Therefore the length of an array is reduced by one.
There are good cases where you may need this, for example, to take the first customer waiting in the queue, but it is very inefficient to use this for the purpose of accessing the first element.

In addition, this requires a perfect array with `[0]` index pointer intact, exactly as using `[0]`;

```
yourArray.shift()
```

***The important thing to know is that the two above are only an option if your array starts with a `[0]` index.***

There are cases where the first element has been deleted, for example with `delete yourArray[0]`, leaving your array with "holes". Now the element at [0] is simply undefined, but you want to get the first "existing" element. I have seen many real world cases of this.

So, assuming we have no knowledge of the array and the first key (or we know there are holes), we can still get the first element.

You can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first element.

The advantage of `find()` is its efficiency as it exits the loop when the first value satisfying the condition is reached (more about this below).
(You can customize the condition to exclude null or other empty values too)

```
var firstItem = yourArray.find(x=>x!==undefined);
```

I'd also like to include [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here as an option to first "fix" the array in the copy and then get the first element while keeping the original array intact (unmodified).

Another reason to include `filter()` here is that it existed before `find()` and many programmers have already been using it (it is ES5 against `find()` being ES6).

```
var firstItem = yourArray.filter(x => typeof x!==undefined).shift();
```

Warning that `filter()` is not really an efficient way (`filter()` runs through all elements) and creates another array. It is fine to use on small arrays as performance impact would be marginal, closer to using `forEach()`, for example.

Another one I have seen in some projects is [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to get the first item in an array and then get it by index:

```
var firstItem = yourArray.splice(0, 1)[0];
```

I am not sure why you would do that. This method won't solve the problem with holes in an array (sparse array). It is costly as it will re-index the array, and it returns an array that you have to access again to get the value. For example, if you delete the first couple of elements, then `splice()` will return `undefined` instead of the first defined value from the array.

Both `find()` and `filter()` guarantee the order of elements, so are safe to use as above.

**(I see some people suggest using loops to get the first element, but I would recommend against this method. Obviously, you can use any loop to get a value from an array but why would you do that?
Readability, optimization, unnecessary block of code etc. When using native functions, the browser can better optimize your code. And it may not even work with some loops which don't guarantee the order in iteration.

By the way, `forEach()` doesn't solve the issue as many suggest because you can't break it and it will run through all elements. You would be better off using a simple `for` loop and by checking key/value, but why?**

Answer (score 142):

**Using ES6 destructuring**

```
let [first] = [1,2,3];
```

Which is the same as

```
let first = [1,2,3][0];
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `const` instead of `let` in this example since it should be used in most cases

Comment: Up to you as long as it's not `var` :-)

Answer (score 142):

### You can just use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const first = array.find(Boolean)
```

**Or** if you want the first element even **if it is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**:

```
const first = array.find(() => true)
```

**Or** if you want the first element even **if it is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) but not if it is undefined** ([more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924076/7910454)):

```
const first = array.find(e => typeof e !== 'undefined')
```

---

**Going the extra mile:**

If you care about readability but don't want to rely on numeric incidences you could add a `first()`-function to [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) by defining it with [`Object​.define​Property()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) which mitigates the pitfalls of modifying the built-in Array object prototype directly ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype)).

Performance is pretty good ([`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) stops after the first element) but it isn't perfect or universally accessible (ES6 only). For more background read [@Selays answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180125/7910454).

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'first', {
  value() {
    return this.find(e => true)     // or this.find(Boolean)
  }
})
```

To retrieve the first element you are now able to do this:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
array.first()

> 'a'
```

Snippet to see it in action:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'first', {
  value() {
    return this.find(Boolean)
  }
})

console.log( ['a', 'b', 'c'].first() )
```

Comment: Part of the answer above says to use `find(e => typeof e !== 'undefined')` _if you want the first element even if it is falsy but not if it is null or undefined_.

But that's not quite right, since this code _will_ return the first element if it's `null`. This is because [`typeof null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#description) is `"object"` and not `"undefined"`. However, it is true that it will not return `undefined`, since `typeof undefined` _is_ `"undefined"`.

Comment: @NicolasFavre-Felix Good catch! Fixed.

Answer (score 64):

Element of index 0 may not exist if the first element has been deleted:

```js
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
delete a[0];

for (let i in a) {
  console.log(i + ' ' + a[i]);
}
```

Better way to get the first element without jQuery:

```js
function first(p) {
  for (let i in p) return p[i];
}

console.log( first(['a', 'b', 'c']) );
```

Comment: a.entries()[0] should do it :)

Comment: That's because you shouldn't use that kind of for enumeration with an array, as it's enumerating objects and not array members. Use indexing with a traditional for loop instead.

Comment: Similar ES6 approach (also not relying on numeric indices) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115413/7910454

Answer (score 45):

If you want to preserve the **readibility** you could always add a first function to the `Array.protoype`:

```
Array.prototype.first = function () {
    return this[0];
};
```

A then you could easily retrieve the first element:

```
[1, 2, 3].first();
> 1
```

Comment: it is considered to be a very bad practice to tinker with prototypes of base classes in any way for a good reason.

Comment: @DmitryMatveev I agree, I wouldn't use this kind of code in public code bases. All developers must deeply understand javascript to introduce this kind of helper functions.

Comment: that's silly, how is typing `.first()` better than doing `[0]`?

Comment: @jonschlinkert Some languages have indices that start at `1`. `first` is unambiguous in that case.

Comment: what does [].first() return?

Comment: In my test it returns undefined. I am trying to decide if I like it returning undefined.

Comment: This assumes that the first index is 0.

Comment: I remember a thing like that breaking array iteration on IE. Don't add random stuff to prototypes of most basic types.

Comment: **This is flawed!** You added the function as an enumerable property which means it will show up as one of the elements in every for ... in loop over every array (!). [Instead use `Object.defineProperty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115413/7910454)

Answer (score 20):

If your array is not guaranteed to be populated from index zero, you can use `Array.prototype.find()`:

```
var elements = []
elements[1] = 'foo'
elements[2] = 'bar'

var first = function(element) { return !!element }    
var gotcha = elements.find(first)

console.log(a[0]) // undefined
console.log(gotcha) // 'foo'
```

Comment: Won't work in IE11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: I'd advise against using `!!element` as it'll skip falsy values. I'd recommend using `find()` in this manner: `sparse.find((_, index, array) => index in array);`

Comment: Similar approach without dismissing falsy values here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115413/7910454

Answer (score 20):

```
array.find(e => !!e);  // return the first element
```

since "find" return the first element that matches the filter && `!!e` match any element.

**Note**  This works only when the first element is not a "Falsy" : `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `""`, `0`, `undefined`

Comment: this is great and also works great in TypeScript. What about simplifying to `array.find(() => true);`? This allows you to do `[false].find(() => true)` as well.

Comment: @SimonWarta of course `.find(value => true)` is just working as expected… but honestly if you want a cleaner code and to keep the typing in typescript, use the [destructuring](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20%5Bfirst%2C%20second%5D%20%3D%20%5B'first'%2C%202%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20fails%20because%20typescript%20understands%20the%20types%20of%20the%20array%20items%0D%0Afirst%20%3D%3D%3D%20second%3B).

Answer (score 17):

In ES2015 and above, using array destructuring:

```js
const arr = [42, 555, 666, 777]
const [first] = arr
console.log(first)
```

Comment: That's the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/48761812/7910454 but a few months later

Answer (score 13):

I know that people which come from other languages to JavaScript, looking for something like `head()` or `first()` to get the first element of an array, but how you can do that?

Imagine you have the array below:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

In JavaScript, you can simply do:

```
const first = arr[0];
```

or a neater, newer way is:

```
const [first] = arr;
```

But you can also simply write a **function** like...

```
function first(arr) {
   if(!Array.isArray(arr)) return;
   return arr[0];
}
```

If using underscore, there are list of functions doing the same thing you looking for:

```
_.first 

_.head

_.take
```

Answer (score 13):

***ES6 Spread operator + .shift() solution***

Using `myArray.shift()` you can get the 1st element of the array, but `.shift()` will modify the original array, so to avoid this, first you can create a copy of the array with `[...myArray]` and then apply the `.shift()` to this copy:

```js
var myArray = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

var first = [...myArray].shift();        

console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 11):

Only in case you are using underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/) you can do:

```
_.first(your_array);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try `alert(ary[0]);`.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to use Array Destructuring

```
const [first, second, third] = ["Laide", "Gabriel", "Jets"];
console.log(first);  // Output: Laide
console.log(second); // Output: Gabriel
console.log(third);  // Output: Jets
```

Answer (score 7):

Method that **works with arrays**, and it **works with objects** too (beware, objects don't have a guaranteed order!).

I prefer this method the most, because original array is not modified.

```
// In case of array
var arr = [];
arr[3] = 'first';
arr[7] = 'last';
var firstElement;
for(var i in arr){
    firstElement = arr[i];
    break;
}
console.log(firstElement);  // "first"

// In case of object
var obj = {
    first: 'first',
    last: 'last',
};

var firstElement;

for(var i in obj){
    firstElement = obj[i];
    break;
}

console.log(firstElement) // First;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another one for those only concerned with truthy elements

```
ary.find(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 6):

Find the first element in an array using a filter:

In typescript:

```
function first<T>(arr: T[], filter: (v: T) => boolean): T {
    let result: T;
    return arr.some(v => { result = v; return filter(v); }) ? result : undefined;
}
```

In plain javascript:

```
function first(arr, filter) {
    var result;
    return arr.some(function (v) { result = v; return filter(v); }) ? result : undefined;
}
```

And similarly, indexOf:

In typescript:

```
function indexOf<T>(arr: T[], filter: (v: T) => boolean): number {
    let result: number;
    return arr.some((v, i) => { result = i; return filter(v); }) ? result : undefined;
}
```

In plain javascript:

```
function indexOf(arr, filter) {
    var result;
    return arr.some(function (v, i) { result = i; return filter(v); }) ? result : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `ary.slice(0,1).pop();`

In

```js
var ary = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

console.log("1º "+ary.slice(0,1).pop());
console.log("2º "+ary.slice(0,2).pop());
console.log("3º "+ary.slice(0,3).pop());
console.log("4º "+ary.slice(0,4).pop());
console.log("5º "+ary.slice(0,5).pop());
console.log("Last "+ary.slice(-1).pop());
```

array.slice(START,END).pop();

Answer (score 4):

Why not account for times your array might be empty?

```
var ary = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
first = (array) => array.length ? array[0] : 'no items';
first(ary)
// output: first

var ary = [];
first(ary)
// output: no items
```

Answer (score 3):

When there are multiple matches, JQuery's .first() is used for fetching the first DOM element that matched the css selector given to jquery.

You don't need jQuery to manipulate javascript arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use .get(0):

```
alert($(ary).first().get(0));
```

To get the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

A vanilla JS code, no jQuery, no libs, no-nothing.. :P.. It will work if array index does not start at zero as well.

```js
var ary = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
console.log(Object.values(ary)[0]);
```

Comment: How is this different from `ary[0]`? Why would array indices not start at 0?

Comment: @OneCricketeer For some reason indexes don't reset when you delete an element of a JavaScript array

Comment: @SašaĆetković I think that's a problem with how you are deleting? https://ideone.com/1ody3G

Answer (score 2):

Declare a prototype to get ***first array*** element as:

```
Array.prototype.first = function () {
   return this[0];
};
```

Then use it as:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var first = array.first();
var _first = [0, 1, 2, 3].first();
```

Or simply (:

```
first = array[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous examples work well when the array index begins at zero. [thomax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159991/thomax) did not rely on the index starting at zero, but relied on `Array.prototype.find` to which I did not have access. The following solution using [jQuery $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each) worked well in my case.

```
let haystack = {100: 'first', 150: 'second'},
    found = null;

$.each(haystack, function( index, value ) {
    found = value;  // Save the first array element for later.
    return false;  // Immediately stop the $.each loop after the first array element.
});

console.log(found); // Prints 'first'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're chaining a view functions to the array e.g.

`array.map(i => i+1).filter(i => i > 3)`

And want the first element after these functions you can simply add a `.shift()` it doesn't modify the original `array`, its a nicer way then `array.map(i => i+1).filter(=> i > 3)[0]`

If you want the first element of an array without modifying the original you can use `array[0]` or `array.map(n=>n).shift()` (without the map you will modify the original. In this case btw i would suggest the `..[0]` version.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ary = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

console.log(Object.keys(ary)[0]);
```

Make any Object array (`req`), then simply do `Object.keys(req)[0]` to pick the first key in the Object array.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var array= ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
firstElement = array[array.length - array.length];
```

https://playcode.io/908187

Answer (score 1):

```
var ary = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"];
console.log(ary.shift());
//first
cosnole.log(ary);
// ["second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]
```

Comment: For answers that cause side-effects, please note them in the answer. In this case, the array is modified.

Comment: Please also check other answers before posting. This answer has [already been provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180125/5648954).

Comment: This will work fine, but mutating values can easily cause bugs.

A slightly safer option could be to clone `ary` so it doesn't mutate: `[...ary].shift()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the other answers is that many won't handle cases where the array is empty or undefined, and the ones that do handle this are either hard to read or require using a library.

The cleanest pure JavaScript way I can think to handle this is by using optional chaining and a ternary operator:

`const first = array?.length ? array[0] : undefined`

You can also do this without optional chaining if you need to support older browsers:

`const first = array && array.length ? array[0] : undefined`

The other advantage of this is that if you need to return a value other than `undefined` (eg returning `null` in a React component) you easily update the code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

@NicoLwk You should remove elements with splice, that will shift your array back. So:

```js
var a=['a','b','c'];
a.splice(0,1);
for(var i in a){console.log(i+' '+a[i]);}
```

Comment: This answer is a comment to aboves (NicoLwks) answer, and should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6.

```
let arr = [22,1,4,55,7,8,9,3,2,4];

let {0 : first ,[arr.length - 1] : last} = arr;
console.log(first, last);
```

or

```
let {0 : first ,length : l, [l - 1] : last} = [22,1,4,55,7,8,9,3,2,4];
console.log(first, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `slice(start,end)` method returns a shallow copy of a part of an array into a new array object selected from `start` to `end` position:

```
  const numbers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
  const selectedNum = numbers.slice(0, 1)[0]
  console.log(selectedNum) // "first"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get first value of an array

```
const dummyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(dummyArray[0]) // 1
```

You can use array de-structure to get first value

```
const dummyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
const [fisrt ,...remaining] = dummyArray
console.log(fisrt) // 1
console.log(remaining) //[2,3,4,5]
```

If You want to create a function that will return first value of array index.

```
const fisrtElement = (arr) => {
if(Array.isArray && Array.isArray(arr) ) {
    return arr[0] || 0
  }
  return 0
}

const first = fisrtElement(dummyArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to split character in javascript.

```
var str = "boy, girl, dog, cat";
var arr = str.split(",");
var fst = arr.splice(0,1).join("");
var rest = arr.join(",");
```

Comment: Question didn't ask how to split/parse a string

Answer (score -1):

@thomax 's answer is pretty good, but will fail if the first element in the array is false or false-y (0, empty string, etc.). Better to just return true for anything other than undefined:

```
const arr = [];
arr[1] = '';
arr[2] = 'foo';

const first = arr.find((v) => { return (typeof v !== 'undefined'); });
console.log(first); // ''
```

Answer (score -1):

ES6 easy:

```
let a = []
a[7] = 'A'
a[10] = 'B'

let firstValue = a.find(v => v)
let firstIndex = a.findIndex(v => v)
```

Comment: Nope… it will return the first defined value. If the first one is null, undefined, false, 0 or an empty string, that one will be skipped.
Try: ```[false, 0, null, undefined, '', 'last'].find(v => v)```

Comment: Good point, my solution works only for array with defined values.

Comment: Then why to filter using the value? `a.find(value => true)` won't dismiss any values. Still, I do not recommend using find to get the first item.

Comment: @FlavienVolken I used something similar in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115413/7910454). Why would you not recommend using it?

Comment: @MiXT4PE returning true (as in your answer) is okay because it will stop at the first element, here it returns the element itself… which will continue if that one is considered false

Comment: @FlavienVolken Thanks for the fast response but I was talking about using `find()` in general because you wrote: *Still, I do not recommend using find to get the first item.*

Comment: @MiXT4PE using "find" is slower, more complicated and less elegant. I also doubt there is any smart editor able to refactor this operation. Using destructuring is much more efficient, understood by the language (so you can refactor), the type is understood by the compiler (in case of TS), and very likely the fastest solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

// Main function.
const example = arr => check(arr) ? getFirstElement(arr) : 0;

// To get the first element of an array.
const getFirstElement = arr => (arr.first() !== '' && arr.first()) ? arr.first() : 'Element is Empty.';

// To check if an array is empty or exists.
const check = arr => (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length) ? true : false;

// Custom property or you can just create custom function.
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'first', {
  value() {
    return this.at(0);
  }
});

console.log(example(arr)); // first
```