# Get value from json object without count the array number

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json object i want to get alert it without the array order like[0], [1].

```
  var jsononj = {
    "objnew" : 
    [{testarry: "thi is my demo text" },
{testarry2: "thi is my demo text2" }
] }; 

    }

var newtest = jsononj.objnew[0].testarry;
    alert(newtest);
```

i want to alert without [0]. how to i achieve this

Comment: What bothers you with the `[0]`? You have an array with 2 elements and you want to show some information from the first element. How do you expect that to happen without telling the system that you want the *first* element? Javascript is not that intelligent enough to be able to read your mind, yet.

Comment: these order can be rearrange anytime but "key" would remain the same thats the reason

Comment: Where did you see *a key*? In the example you have shown I can only see a message. You see, that's what happens when you are not telling us everything and showing your real code and real problem.

Comment: key i mean here is  :testarry this would remain the same

Comment: I think @SachinRawal is looking for a way to iterate trough the json in order to find the array that contains a given key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < jsonobj.objnew.length; i++) {
    if (jsonobj.objnew[i].testarry) {
        alert(jsonobj.objnew[i].testarry);
    }
}
```

Comment: var i is needed? I don't understand the point. Where are you using that index?

Comment: Oops, made a mistake. Forgot the `[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

doing a  `var firstOne = jsononj.objnew[0];`

but if you simply don't like the `[0]`  through your lines, extend the Array prototype

```
Array.prototype.first = function () {
    return this[0];
};
var newtest = jsononj.objnew.first().testarry;
alert(newtest);
```

more info at [First element in array - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090491/first-element-in-array-jquery)

Comment: You are cheating, you still used `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just stupid but I removed the `[0]`

```
var jsononj = {
    "objnew" : [
        {testarry: "thi is my demo text" },
        {testarry2: "thi is my demo text2" }
    ]
};

var a = jsononj.objnew.shift();
alert(a.testarry);
jsononj.objnew.unshift(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON, that's a Javascript object. JSON is a text format for representing data.

If you want to look for an object with a specific property, loop through the objects in the array and check for it:

```
var newtest = null;
for (var i = 0; i < jsononj.objnew.length; i++) {
  var obj = jsononj.objnew[i];
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('testarry') {
    newtest = obj.testarry;
    break;
  }
}
if (newtest != null) {
  // found one
}
```