# Getting the first item in an [word, word]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the first word out of the variable `var solution = [cow, pig]`
I have tried everything from strings to arrays and I can't get it. Please help.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090491/first-element-in-array-jquery

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to coding and I didn't know that solution[0] was a thing, thank you.

Comment: You'll learn what's "a thing" and what's not if you take the time to read a beginners JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: I like that the OP's name is CodeMaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments

```
solution[0]
```

Will return the first item in the array.

```
solution[1]
```

would be the second, or `undefined` if the array was:

```
var solution = [cow]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is solution an array, or is it in that form?  (`var solution = [cow, pig]`) You also need to add quotes around those values, unless those values are defined variables.

You need to change the variable to look like this:

`var solution = ['cow', 'pig']`

If so, just get the value at subscript 0.

```
var result = solution[0];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an string like

```
solution = "cow pig".
```

Do

```
solution = solution.split(' ')[0];
   console.log(solution); //Will return cow
```