# Extract value from array of objects in Postman

Tags: json, environment-variables, postman

I want to extract Id value from the array with objects in Postman and then set it as an environment variable. In case JSON response is an object, the following script works, but not with an array of objects (my array has only one object).

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("userid", data.Id);
```

JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1287,
    "LastName": "Trump",
    "FirstName": "Donald",
    "MiddleName": "Von",
    "City": "New York City",
    "Phone": "66 77 88",
    "State": "New York",
    "Fax": "111-222-333",
    "ReferenceId": "12345",
    "Active": false,
    "CurrentWorkingSchemeId": null
  }
]
```

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the first element of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090491/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If it is an array of objects, then just select the first object using index [0] before grabbing the object's key like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);   
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("userid", data[0].Id);
```

Comment: Great. Works like a charm :)

Comment: @UrošKočevar, I think you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works like charm!
Basically what i am doing here is, parse the response and from the data array, take id and save it in postman environment variable.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) `
    {
    var counter = jsonData.data[i];
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("schID", counter.id);
    }
```

Comment: I was looking something like this i wonder if can execute a request for each value extracted from the array?

Comment: for(const item of jsonData) { /* use item here in loop */ }