# Find an object in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
['test', 'test2', {a: a, b: b}, 'test3']
```

How can I get the first object only?

Would I need to loop through and do a type test? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090491/get-first-element-in-array)

Comment: No, he means how do you find the first item of the array of type object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would I need to loop through and do a type test?

You do, or at least, *something* does.

For instance, to find the first object in the array, you could use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const first = theArray.find(e => typeof e === "object");
```

Or if you don't want `null` to match:

```
const first = theArray.find(e => e && typeof e === "object");
```

> Or is there a more efficient way?

Looping's going to be sufficiently efficient. If you don't like the calls to `find`'s callback (they're **really, really, really** fast), you could use a boring old `for` loop:

```
let first;
for (let i = 0, l = theArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
    const e = theArray[i];
    if (typeof e === "object") { // Or, again: `e && typeof e === "object"`
        first = e;
        break;
    }
}
```

...but the odds that it makes a performance difference you can actually perceive are vanishingly small.

Comment: To elaborate for the OP: `Array.find` just loops through the array and stops when it finds the first element that matches your test -- that is, the first element that makes the callback function return true. As long as your array doesn't have any well-defined order (for instance, alphabetical or numerical or something), the best you can ever do is a linear search, as you don't know what elements comes after which.

Comment: Is it supported in ie? I know no one cares about ie but anyways

Comment: @Timggwp - Re `find` in IE: No, you'd need a polyfill (which is easily come by).

Comment: you need tho check the value, too: `e => e && typeof e === "object")`.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Depends on what the OP wants. If they don't want `null` to match, then yes, they need that.

Comment: @NinaScholz i think the answer given fully satisfies the question since `null`'s type is `object` :)

Comment: @Timggwp - :-) Nevertheless, it's a good point I added to the answer and probably should have mentioned before she brought it up.