# How to get the index of first element in array without loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of size 5010.
For example, a=[0...5009] and my first element is placed at index 5002 which is dynamic and may change.
So, how do I get directly the first element of the array without looping through array in javascript.

Comment: What do you mean first element? The first element is at `a[0]`

Comment: Need more insights for What is first element

Comment: your first element is at index 0. if you want the item at 5002 use `myArray[5002]`...

Comment: If you want to avoid writing a for loop, you can use `Array.filter()` for example. Which loops internally. Avoiding a loop at all isn't possible. Besides, I guess you are referring to your first element as a object with e.g id: 1 at position 5002

Comment: If your object has an unique id you may use the `.find` method. `arr.find( item => item.id === YOUR_ID )`

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of looping.

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a sparse array and return `true` for the first nonsparsed item, after assigning the value to a variable.

This approach works for any value, even for `undefined` or `null` or any other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

```js
var array = [],
    index;

array.length = 5010;
array[5002] = null;

array.some((_, i) => (index = i, true));
console.log(index);
```

[`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) does not work with **unknown value**, because it visits every element, even the sparse elements.

```js
var array = [],
    index;

array.length = 5010;
array[5002] = 'some value'

index = array.findIndex((v, i) => (console.log(i, v), true));
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the previous elements are undefined, you may need to filter the array first to get only defined values in the array.

const definedValues = array.filter(item => item);
definedValues[0] // this will gives you the first defined item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the index of an element whose value you already have, use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var list = [1,2,3];
console.log(list.indexOf(2)); // 1
```

If you want to find the index using a function, use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
var list = [1,2,3];
console.log(list.findIndex(item => item === 2)); // 1
```

So if you want to find the first element that is a troothy do:

```js
var list = [null,2,3];
console.log(list.findIndex(item => item)); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

var firstElement = array1.shift();

console.log(array1); // expected output: Array [2, 3]

console.log(firstElement); // expected output: 1
```

Here you can find some other examples [Get first element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090491/get-first-element-in-array)