# JavaScript Array Manipulation: Remove Specific Items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working with JavaScript arrays recently, and I've come across a situation where I need to remove certain items from an array. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
let myArray = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry'];
```

Let's say I need to remove the 'banana' and 'date' from this array. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? I would ideally like the solution to be scalable, in case I need to remove more items in the future.

I know that I could use a loop to iterate through the array and splice the array when the item is found, like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] === 'banana' || myArray[i] === 'date') {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a better, more JavaScript-esque way to accomplish this task. Also, I've heard that using splice within a loop can lead to issues due to the changing indices.

Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

I am expecting better results.

Comment: PSA: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) exists. [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript).

Comment: Check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310559/the-best-way-to-remove-array-element-by-value)

Comment: `within a loop can lead to issues due to the changing indices`,  yes that's why you did -> `i--;` after you spliced, another option to avoid that is do the loop in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about performance and just go for [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as:

- It's the simplest and easier to read/understand implementation.
- Works with multiple occurrences of the same item.
- Seems to be the fastest anyway (this might change depending on the shape and size of you data and browser).

Anyway, here's a playground with different option for you to take a look and experiment:

```js
function measure(name, callback, runs = 100000) {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= runs; ++i) {
    callback()
  }
  
  const t1 = performance.now() - t0;
  
  console.log(name, t1, 'ms')
}

const myArray = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry'];
const myElementsToRemove = ['banana', 'date'];

function removeMultipleWithSpliceClone(arr, elementsToRemove) {
  const newArr = arr.slice(0)
  
  for (const elementToRemove of elementsToRemove) {
    // This won't work for multiple ocurrences of the same item:
    const index = newArr.indexOf(elementToRemove)
    
    if (index >= 0) {
      newArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

function removeMultipleWithSpliceMutate(arr, elementsToRemove) { 
  for (const elementToRemove of elementsToRemove) {
    // This won't work for multiple ocurrences of the same item:
    const index = arr.indexOf(elementToRemove)
    
    if (index >= 0) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

function removeMultipleWithFilter(arr, elementsToRemove) {
  return arr.filter((element) => !elementsToRemove.includes(element))
}

function removeMultipleWithForAndPush(arr, elementsToRemove) {
  const newArr = []
  
  for (const element of arr) {
    if (!elementsToRemove.includes(element)) newArr.push(element)
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

// console.log(removeMultipleWithSpliceClone(myArray, myElementsToRemove))
// console.log(removeMultipleWithSpliceMutate(myArray, myElementsToRemove))
// console.log(removeMultipleWithFilter(myArray, myElementsToRemove))
// console.log(removeMultipleWithForAndPush(myArray, myElementsToRemove))

measure('removeMultipleWithSpliceClone', () => {
  removeMultipleWithSpliceClone(myArray, myElementsToRemove)
})

measure('removeMultipleWithSpliceMutate', () => {
  removeMultipleWithSpliceMutate([...myArray], myElementsToRemove)
})

measure('removeMultipleWithFilter', () => {
  removeMultipleWithFilter(myArray, myElementsToRemove)
})

measure('removeMultipleWithForAndPush', () => {
  removeMultipleWithForAndPush(myArray, myElementsToRemove)
})
```

Comment: `I would not worry about performance`,  Totally agree with that statement.  But a slight observation, -> `removeMultipleWithSplice` , if your going to use `splice` your likely wanting to mutate the array, your version copies the array and then mutates taking away any speed advantage, also using `forEach` would have a performance impact here too,  a-> `for (let x = arr.length -1; x >= 0; x --) {` would likely give you a performance boost, as it avoids callback overhead.   ps: the descending loop is deliberate as it avoids index issues the OP was talking about.

Comment: @Keith You are right, I've updated the answer to include an option that mutates the array you pass and changed `forEach` to `for`. I'm not using the descending loop thought as my examples do not iterate the elements in the array you want to filter like the one provided by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Array indexOf() function ti find the index of an element, and then Array.splice() to remove it, in a loop for all elements to be removed.

Optional checks depending on circumstances: Is there such an element? Is there another such an element?