# Get length of longest String in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i need to find out the longest string of an array. First of all i push different "text" elements into my array, since the stringe and amount of those "text" elements can differ from case to case. (they are lables of an chart and thus are generated based on the charts sections.

my code right now looks like this:

```
 var textLengthArray = [];
            domContainer.find(" g > .brm-y-direction > .tick > text").each(function () {
                textLengthArray.push($(this));
            });
            var lgth = 0;
            var longestString;
            for (var i = 0; i < textLengthArray.length; i++) {
                if (textLengthArray[i].length > lgth) {
                    var lgth = textLengthArray[i].length;
                    longestString = textLengthArray[i];
                }
            }
```

It already pushes all text elements into my array. But when i use

```
 alert(longestString.length)
```

i allway get "1" as a result. I am pretty shure i have to add .text anywhere before .length, since the code does not check die textlength of the textelements.
Since i am quite new to javascript i would highly appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm running this and it works - although I'm using a hardcoded array of strings instead of the `domContainer.find` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textLengthArray.push($(this));` should be `textLengthArray.push($(this).text());` otherwise your array consists of jQuery objects. And indeed jQuerySet has `length` property. And in your case the set consists of 1 element.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works just as it should!

Comment: @SaltyM, then please mark this as an answer, or modify the question if it doesn't. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring `lgth` in each iteration of the array which is re-assigning the value.

Replace `var lgth = textLengthArray[i].length` with `lgth = textLengthArray[i].length` and you should be good.

Comment: then it should return 0 and not 1

Comment: @ParvSharma what do you mean?  It should return the length of the longest string in the array..?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the rest of your code, looks fine. But you're pushing a jQuery object`$(this)`, not a string. Line three should read `textLengthArray.push(this);`.

Apparently one of the strings your pushing is a valid jQuery selector that finds an element :-)

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a separate array. Just iterate objects and update as you go:

```js
longest = "";

$('div').each(function() { 
  var t = $(this).text();
  if(t.length > longest.length)
    longest = t;
});

alert(longest)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>hello</div>
<div>wonderful</div>
<div>world</div>
```

To get the longest string from any array, try `reduce`:

```js
a = ['hello', 'wonderful', 'world']

longest = a.reduce(function(prev, e) {
  return prev.length >= e.length ? prev : e;  
});

alert(longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array by length and get the first element. Hope it works for you

[stackoverflow.com/questions/10630766/sort-an-array-based-on-the-length-of-each-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630766/sort-an-array-based-on-the-length-of-each-element)