# How do I sort an array based on the count of a character in a string?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a couple of strings in an array.

For example:

```
[
    "path/to/file",
    "path",
    "path/to/",
    "path2/to/file",
    "path2/to/file",
    "path2/to"
]
```

etc...

The thing that i would like to achieve is to sort the array based on the the count of the slash. So the less count slashes on top.

So it would be like:

```
[
    "path",
    "path/to/",
    "path2/to",
    "path/to/file",
    "path2/to/file",
    "path2/to/file"
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array based on the length of each element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630766/how-to-sort-an-array-based-on-the-length-of-each-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.split("/").length - b.split("/").length;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the custom function of Array sort method like this

```
var array_strings = ["path","path/to/","path/to/file"];
array_strings.sort(function(a, b){
  var a_length = a.split('/').length;
  var b_length = b.split('/').length;
  return a_length - b.length;
});
```