# How can I sort an array by number of letters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, letter

Trying to sort an array of strings by the number of letters of each array's value, I have this array:

```
 var list = ["rrr", "re", "r", "rrar"]
```

And the Output would be:

```
var list = ["r", "re", "rrr", "rrar"];
```

This is my code:

```
        var list = ["rrr", "re", "r", "rrar"];
    n = 4;
    x = -1;
    document.write(" list before: " + list);

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        list[x] = list;

        for (i = 0; i < n-k; i++) {

            if (list[i + 1].length < list[i].length) {
                aux = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    document.write(" list after: " + list);
```

I don't understand why Chrome's Console gives me a "TypeError: list[(i + 1)] is undefined", I'm trying but I don't find where define that

Comment: `list.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.lenght)`

Comment: @RashadKokash, answers go down there. You short-circuit the process when you post them as comments.

Comment: because you are on the last index and you are trying to read the next index. There is no index after the last index

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel: just use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
list.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```

Comment: OK, now I see it's solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630766/how-to-sort-an-array-based-on-the-length-of-each-element