# Why modifying `Array.prototype` doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/53ranmn5/1

```
Array.prototype.method1 = function() {
console.log("method1 called");
}
[1,2,3,4].method1();
```

I get the following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property `'method1'` of `undefined`

Why so? How can I fix this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53ranmn5/1/

Comment: Is the above working for you?

Comment: Your code works just fine, although `console.log([1,2,3,4].method1());` prints out undefined (in your fiddle) since method1 does not return any string itself.

Comment: You've included what you tried, but not what you expect or what went wrong.

Comment: What was your expected output. The actual output is 
method1 called
undefined
method2 called

Which is what I would expect.

Comment: @gopalrao My bad. Your code has a real problem. You should use `;` after the function definition. JavaScript treats `function () {..}[1, 2, 3,4]` as a Single expression. And since it returns `undefined`, you are getting the error.

Comment: You guys are too quick to close, he's getting an undefined error, try running it yourself. OP is looking for `Object.defineProperty`[as seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/53ranmn5/2/).

Comment: @ScottKaye Nope, check my previous comment.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to close so quickly - I didn't see his error as immediately obvious either.

Comment: @ScottKaye That is why I apologized and voted to reopen.

Comment: @ thefourtheye anyway it should be closed as simple typo errors, but strange why js not  worked automatic insertion of semicolons to end statements.

Comment: @ScottKaye if you see fiddle from OP not in comment - all working

Comment: @Grundy Hmmm, Is it really a typo? I have seen code where people don't use `;`s at all. I think this question deserves a decent explanation.

Comment: I thought the typo flag was more suited for things like `var test = 3; console.log(tset)`, I'd say this is more of a "feature" of Javascript going wrong.

Comment: @Grundy Right, but it works for the wrong reason - having `console.log()` triggers Javascript to put an automatic semicolon after the prototype definition, which allows the rest of the code to work.

Comment: Regardless of the problem with the code, the question has a slew of problems on its own. The question was closed and downvoted because it does not show *any* effort nor does it contain a minimal example, desired behavior, and actual behavior. Using the example to reproduce some error and editing that into the question -- without knowing if it is the same error the OP was seeing -- is questionable, at best.

Answer (score 10):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
Array.prototype.method1 = function() {
    console.log("method1 called");
}; // <--- Hi there!
[1,2,3,4].method1();
```

### What?

Semicolons are optional in javascript, so the code you wrote is equivalent to:

```
Array.prototype.method1 = function() { ... }[1,2,3,4].method1();
// after evaluating the comma operator:
Array.prototype.method1 = function() { ... }[4].method1();
// naturally, functions don't have a fourth index
undefined.method1();
// Error :(
```

Be careful with your semicolons!

Some reading material:

- [What does a comma do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do)
- [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)
- http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons
- Specification: [Latest stable (es5)](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9), [Draft (es2015)](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion).

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, just added one character:

```
Array.prototype.method1 = function() {
    console.log("method1 has been called");
};
[1,2,3,4].method1();
```

Comment: Please explain why the "one character" is necessary here.

Comment: Your code is correct, when run under console. This bug must belong to jsfiddle alone. Compare it with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype

Comment: @Beri When run inside a console, statement by statement, the bug isn't there because the array isn't there to confuse the js engine into thinking it's a property access.