# split array of objects in javascript into separate arrays based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array like this:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
  { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214, status: "walking" },
  { lat: 36.772, lng: -123.214, status: "walking" },
  { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821, status: "automotive" },
  { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431, status: "automotive" },
  { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027, status: "walking" },
  { lat: -26.467, lng: 151.027, status: "walking" },
];
```

and I want this to be split up into three arrays that have objects that have the same type like this following format:

```
[{lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214, status: 'walking'},
{lat: 36.772, lng: -123.214, status: 'walking'}]

[{lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821, status: 'automotive'},
{lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431, status: 'automotive'}]

[{lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027, status: 'walking'}
{lat: -26.467, lng: 151.027, status: 'walking'}]
```

I cannot just use groupBy to handle this, any ideas?

Comment: Why did you put a bounty on this @geekymano ? What's wrong in Nina Scholz's answer?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a group change if status is changing.

```js
var flightPlanCoordinates = [{ lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214, status: 'walking' }, { lat: 36.772, lng: -123.214, status: 'walking' }, { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821, status: 'automotive' }, { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431, status: 'automotive' }, { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027, status: 'walking' }, { lat: -26.467, lng: 151.027, status: 'walking' }],
    grouped = flightPlanCoordinates.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (!i || r[r.length - 1][0].status !== a.status) {
            return r.concat([[a]]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for-loop, When the current element status is different from previous elements status, Then push the `slice` of array to output array.

```js
const split = (arr) => {
  const output = [];
  let last = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]?.status !== arr[i - 1]?.status) {
      output.push(arr.slice(last, i));
      last = i;
    }
  }
  return output;
};

var flightPlanCoordinates = [
  { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214, status: "walking" },
  { lat: 36.772, lng: -123.214, status: "walking" },
  { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821, status: "automotive" },
  { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431, status: "automotive" },
  { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027, status: "walking" },
  { lat: -26.467, lng: 151.027, status: "walking" },
];

console.log(split(flightPlanCoordinates));
```

Answer (score 1):

First we need to create a `groupBy` function as described in [Nina's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590535/4110233). Then [attach this function to the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684116/4110233) of the array object so it becomes available globally like map and reduce. It can then be accessed using `array.groupBy(key)`. The newly defined `groupBy` function will be available for all other arrays as well.

```js
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
  { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214, status: "walking" },
  { lat: 36.772, lng: -123.214, status: "walking" },
  { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821, status: "automotive" },
  { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431, status: "automotive" },
  { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027, status: "walking" },
  { lat: -26.467, lng: 151.027, status: "walking" },
];


Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
    return this.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (!i || r[r.length - 1][0][key] !== a[key]) {
            return r.concat([[a]]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
};

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates.groupBy("status"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue, that it's not question, just asking for code writing... Nonetheless

```js
        Array.prototype.group_by_sequenced = function (field_name){
            var result = new Array();
            var j=0;
            for (var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
                var tmp = this[i];
                if (i==0) {
                    result[j]= new Array();
                } else if (this[i-1][field_name]!=this[i][field_name]) {
                    j++;
                    result[j] = new Array();
                }
                result[j].push(tmp);
            }
            return result;
        }
        
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [{ lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214, status: "walking" },{ lat: 36.772, lng: -123.214, status: "walking" },{ lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821, status: "automotive" }, { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431, status: "automotive" },  { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027, status: "walking" },  { lat: -26.467, lng: 151.027, status: "walking" }];
        var res = flightPlanCoordinates.group_by_sequenced('status');
        
        console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheChetan's answer is far from ideal IMO it does not work well when the order of the elements in the initial array is not a happy order (unless it's a desired behavior but I doubt it).

Find below my proposal of solving it:

```
export const groupArrayByElementKey = (arr = [], key) => {
    if (!arr.some(el => key in el)) {
        return arr;
    }

    return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const existingGroupIndex = acc.findIndex(el => el[0][key] === curr[key]);

        if (!acc[existingGroupIndex]) {
            return acc.concat([[curr]]);
        } else {
            acc[existingGroupIndex].push(curr);
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);
};
```