# "dot function" operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, prototype

I'm a total newbie in js, so please be gentle with me :)

I want to understand where can we use the dot operator on some variable (in this case - an array), and when we cannot.
consider the following code:

```
//example 1
function f1(x) {
    return x*x;
}
console.log(map(f1, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].map(f1));

//example 2
function f2(arr) {
    return arr;
}
console.log(f2([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].f2());
```

I know the examples are rather different, but still - in example 1 both prints work (and print the same) - even when using the `array.function(..)` syntax, while in example 2 the second print raises an error.
basically, what is the difference between the two, and why does it work only in example 1?

and generally - can I apply this method over different variable types (numbers, booleans, etc.)?

Comment: To complete other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example your are using the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

This function can be called in 2 different ways (See the docs)

```
[1,2,3].map(function(x){ ... }): //In your case the callback function is *f1()*
```

*OR*

```
arr.map(callback, [1,2,3]);
```

The second example is not working because the class `Array` has not function called `f2()`

Answer (score 1):

`[1,2,3,4,5]` is an instance of Array "class", and that "class" has [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, that's why the following is a valid code:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(f1)
```

`map` method can accept any function as a parameter, and you're passing in your `f1` function. It will be executed inside `map` function and it's executed as a standalone function.

Array "class" doesn't have `f2` method, that's why this is invalid code:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].f2()
```

Here, `f2` is executed immediately and is a part of `[1,2,3,4,5]` object

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `map` is defined as both a global function **and** public function of the `Array`. You can therefore call it via `map(arr)` or `arr.map(..)`

In the second case, as you only defined f2 as a global function which means the array can't access it.