# How can I make a sub-function for a pre-existing data type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to make a function that appends to an array that I can then call by using `arrayname.Function()`. However, I have no idea how to do this; can anyone help?

Comment: your question is not clear at all, please provide a better description

Comment: Add functions to `Array.prototype` like: `Array.prototype.func = ...`. But bear in mind that this is not recommended.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype