# Implementing reduce() from scratch, not sure how JS knows what "array" is

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying to implement reduce() from scratch. I was able to get it working, but how does javascript know what "array" is even though I never defined it anywhere?

```
function reduce(callback, initialVal) {
  var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (accumulator !== undefined) {
      accumulator = callback(accumulator, array[i], i, array);
    } else {
      accumulator = array[i]
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
};

// testing a basic sum
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.reduce( (accumulator, elem) => accumulator+=elem )
```

EDIT: I got it working :D I Changed 'array' to "this" since I was creating a new method under Array.prototype.

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
  var accumulator = (initialVal !== undefined) ? initialVal : undefined;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
    if (accumulator !== undefined) {
      accumulator = callback(accumulator, this[i], i, this);
    } else {
      accumulator = this[i]
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
};

arr.myReduce( (accumulator, elem) => accumulator+=elem )
arr.myReduce( (accumulator, elem) => accumulator+=elem , 100)
```

Comment: you need to create [array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).And also `array.reduce` overwrite the default js is bad practise.its affected the library of you are included.Better use different name instead js default

Comment: Are you sure YOUR code is getting called and not built in `reduce` that is on `Array`'s `prototype`?

Comment: `[` and `]` tells JS that it's an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding custom functions into Array.prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype)

Comment: @prasanth you guys are right, it's most likely calling the native reduce() and not the one I just created...if I change the function to "myReduce()" it throws the error "TypeError: arr.myReduce is not a function". I'll retry by creating it under Array.prototype!

Answer (score 15):

You are pretty close. The one insight that seems to be missing is that inside your function, `this` will be defined as the array your function was called on. So you can use `this` in the places you're currently using `array`, which in your function will be undefined (as you suspected). You probably also want to start the loop in a different place depending on whether the initial value was passed in. For example:

```js
function reduce(callback, initialVal) {
    var accumulator = ( initialVal === undefined) ? this[0] : initialVal;
    var start = (initialVal === undefined) ? 1 : 0
    for (var i = start; i < this.length; i++) {
        accumulator = callback(accumulator, this[i])
    }
    return accumulator;
  };

Array.prototype.myReduce = reduce

// no init value
console.log([1, 2, 3].myReduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr))

// init value:
console.log([1, 2, 3].myReduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr, 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Crisp and clear

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, iterator) {
if (typeof this[0] === "number" && iterator === undefined) {
    iterator = 0;
} else if (typeof this[0] === "string" && iterator === undefined) {
    iterator = ""
}
for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    iterator = callback(iterator, this[i]);
}
return iterator;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).