# Referencing 'this' to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I had this wild thought of adding a method to an array - i just don't know if this is possible. I'll forever be indebted to some knowledge you might share :)

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.hello = () => {return this};
console.log(arr['hello']()); //outputs an empty object {}
```

1. If `[arr]` is ultimately an object, wouldn't `this` refer to `[arr]`?
2. At the end of the day, I just wanted to get `arr[0]` via `this`

Comment: arrow functions have a lexical `this`

Comment: Array elements can't be addressed by key as they have no key.

Comment: "I had this wild thought of adding a method to an array" just don't. Make it a function accepting array as the first argument.

Comment: Also you can't use `arrow` functions as methods. It captures context [lexically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Related: [adding custom functions into Array.prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/948358)

Comment: thanks masters! I finally understood what went wrong. What a great help!! :))