# How to chain useState() method from React hook

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks, method-chaining

Is it possible to chain a React hook? If so, how?

A typical application of a hook would look like this:

```
const [inv, updateInventory] = useState([])
a = ["cheese", "bread", "apples"]
b = a.filter(isDairy)
updateInventory(b)
```

We can also do this, but it's not chained:

```
const [inv, updateInventory] = useState([])
a =  ["cheese", "bread", "apples"]
updateInventory(a.filter(isDairy))
```

What I want is a chained hook in a functional style:

```
const [inv, updateInventory] = useState([])
a =  ["cheese", "bread", "apples"]
a.filter(isDairy).updateInventory()
```

Can a hook can be modified to take state from `this`?

Comment: You could import stage 1 and use the pipeline operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator but I don't really see the value in doing this.

Comment: You can add arbitrary methods to arrays by patching the prototype, but I wouldn't recommend it - how many hooks do you have with array values? Do you want them *all* to be methods on arrays?

Comment: Note if you do decide to patch arrays (remember `updateInventory` would be on *every array*, though!) this becomes https://stackoverflow.com/q/948358/3001761

Answer (score 1):

Proper usage would be:

```
updateInventory([...a, "cheddar"].quicksort().filter("cheese"))
```

But if you really want that chaining, look into [how to edit the array prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype).

This is really not recommended, as that method will then be available on *all* arrays.

Comment: I'm thinking ``[...a, "cheddar"].quicksort().filter("cheese").updateInventory()``. Essentially what I'm asking is can the hook be modified to use ``this`` and support chaining? Assuming the ``.filter("cheese")`` method returns ``this``, can updateInventory() be modified to take state from ``this``?

Comment: the `.filter` method returns an Array, so its `this` would be an array, so you'd have to extend the prototype of `array` to do the chaining as you wish

Comment: @kmiklas as I pointed out a few hours ago, you'd have to patch every array in your application to *"to use `this` and support chaining"*. This isn't really anything to do with React.

Comment: This business of extending the array prototype is too narrow an answer; it doesn't speak to the question. I can easily set ``this.arr`` and ``return this``. Is there a way to chain into the hook?

Answer (score 0):

I think the underlying problem is you're not clear on what's actually happening with method chaining and possibly with hooks. The specific question:

> Can a hook can be modified to take state from `this`?

doesn't really make sense. So let's break down *why* then come back at the end to how you *could* approach this.

---

For method chaining, let's try a simple example using two methods, `.filter` and `.map`, that have two important properties:

1. They actually return arrays (unlike `.push`, which returns the new length of the array); and
2. They actually exist on arrays (unlike `.quicksort`, which exists on neither an array nor the integer you were calling it  on).

```
function isDairy(item) {
  return ["cheese", "milk"].includes(item);
}

function getPrice(item) {
  return { bread: 0.58, cheese: 0.80, apples: 0.47, milk: 1.01 }[item];
}

const inStock = ["bread", "cheese", "apples"];

inStock
  .filter(isDairy)
  .map((item) => ({ item, price: getPrice(item) }));
// => [{ item: "cheese", price: 0.8 }]
```

There's nothing particularly special happening here, each method you're calling *returns a new array* on which you can also call any method an array has. You could assign the intermediate steps and get the same result:

```
const filteredStock = stock.filter(isDairy);
// => ["cheese"]
const pricedFilteredStock = filteredStock.map((item) => ({ item, price: getPrice(item) }));
// => [{ item: "cheese", price: 0.8 }]
```

It is **not** the case that:

- these are standalone functions (like in e.g. Python where you `map(callable, iterable)`); or
- that the `item.name` syntax is doing anything beyond just accessing a property named `name` on the `item`.

If I tried to use the `filter` method as a standalone function:

```
filter(isDairy, inStock);
```

that would be a ReferenceError, or if I defined another function and tried to access it as if it was a prop on an array:

```
function allUppercase() { 
  return this.map((item) => item.toUpperCase());
}

inStock.allUppercase();
```

it would be a TypeError (because `isStock.allUppercase` is `undefined` and `undefined` isn't callable).

Note you *could* do `allUppercase.bind(inStock)()` (or the neater `allUppercase.call(inStock)`), though; JavaScript does have a means of setting `this` for a function.

---

When you use the `useState` hook, you're calling a function that returns an array containing two objects, and destructuring that array to two local variables:

```
const [thing, setThing] = useState(initialValue);
```

is equivalent to:

```
const result = useState(initialValue);
const thing = result[0];
const setThing = result[1];
```

The `thing`, `setThing` naming is just a convention; really, we're accessing those two objects (current value and setter function) by position. They *don't have names of their own*, you can do `const [foo, bar] = useState("baz")` (but... don't).

As the setter is a function you might be wondering whether you can use `setThing.bind` here, but if `setThing` *is* written to use `this` (I didn't look into the implementation, as it's not directly relevant), it's *not* going to be happy if you change what `this` is!

---

So this comes together when you try to do:

```
const [basket, setBasket] = useState([]);
            // ^^^^^^^^^

inStock.filter(...).map(...).setBasket();
                          // ^^^^^^^^^
```

As with the example above, this is a TypeError because `setBasket` doesn't exist on the array returned by `.map`. The fact that the same "word" `setBasket` appears twice is **totally irrelevant** as far as JavaScript is concerned; one is a local variable and the other is a prop on an array, there's no connection between them.

`.map(...)` returns a *new* array, one that we didn't already have a reference to, so the only way to make this work is to ensure *all* arrays have a `setBasket` method, which means patching the prototype (as covered in [adding custom functions into Array.prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/948358/3001761)):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "setBasket", {
  value () {
    setBasket(this);
  },
});
```

One problem here is that the *function* `setBasket` is accessed via a closure, so it needs to happen inside the component where the hook is defined, so it's going to get defined every time the component is rendered (or you're going to `useEffect`), which is a problem because you can't *re*define that method as written...

But let's ignore that because the bigger problem is that *every array in your app* now has that method, even in contexts where it's not relevant. If you have multiple state hooks, as seems likely in any non-trivial app, your arrays are gaining lots of methods globally that are only for use in small local scopes.

---

A more feasible approach is to add a generic method that can be used to apply *any* hook (in fact any *function*) to an array:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "andCall", {
  value (func) {
    return func(this);
  },
});
```

This can be added once, globally, and used to apply whatever hook is relevant:

```
inStock.filter(...).map(...).andCall(setBasket);
```

Note that if you're using TypeScript, you'd also have to add the definition to the global array type, e.g.:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        andCall<S>(func: (arr: Array<T>) => S): S;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this write-up. I will read it after work today.