# Using a function inside a Vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I write a function instead of this Replace snippet and use it inside my checkAnswer method?

```
    methods: {

    checkAnswer: function () {

    this.quiz.userInputArray = this.quiz.userAnswerArray.replace('Ğ','g')
      .replace('Ü','u')
      .replace('Ş','s')
      .replace('I','i')
      .replace('ç','c');
    }
```

I want to be able to use it code like this:

```
this.quiz.userInputArray = this.quiz.userAnswerArray.replaceFunc()
```

Comment: you could do `this.quiz.userAnswerArray.map(ans=>ans.replace().replace())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create another method called `replaceFunc`

```js
methods: {
 replaceFunc(arr){
    return arr.replace('Ğ','g')
     .replace('Ü','u')
     .replace('Ş','s')
     .replace('I','i')
     .replace('ç','c');
 },

 checkAnswer(){
    this.quiz.userInputArray = this.replaceFunc(this.quiz.userAnswerArray);
 }
}
```

Otherwise, if you insist on calling `replaceFunc` like this `this.quiz.userAnswerArray.replaceFunc()`, then you can read about adding custom properties to Array.prototype which is considered a bad practice ([adding custom functions into Array.prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype)).